# Is there a way to template a function so that an N-dimensional brace-enclosure initializer list can be input?

Tags: c++, vector, list-initialization

I am working on a function that needs to allow input of an N-dimensional brace-enclosed initializer list, and outputs a 1-D vector. For example, an input of

`std::vector<int> flat_array = flatten({{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}},{{7,8,9},{10,11,12}}});`

would output `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]`. I am attempting to accomplish this recursively in something like the following.

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<int>
flattenVector(const std::vector<std::vector<T>> & vec)
{
  std::vector<T> new_vec(vec[0]);
  for (unsigned int i = 1; i < vec.size(); ++i)
  {
    new_vec.insert(new_vec.end(), vec[i].begin(), vec[i].end());
  }
  return flatten(new_vec);
}

std::vector<int>
flattenVector(const std::vector<int> & vec)
{
  return vec;
}
```

Unfortunately, this won't work due to the inability of the compiler to deduce the template parameter. Is there a way to do this without explicitly writing every nested vector in the function declaration?

Comment: Have you looked into using variadic templates? I'm not the best with them but I think there may be a way you can leverage a variadic template to get what you want.

Comment: After making an attempt I'm actually very curious now to know what the solution to this is.

Comment: Hm ... well, this is hard. Failed, too.

Comment: I have a feeling something in this "https://arne-mertz.de/2016/11/more-variadic-templates/" might be the answer but it's a bit over my head at the moment lol

Comment: Try changing the argument to `flattenVector()` from nested `std::vector<>`s to nested `std::initializer_list<>`s.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 Have you come up with any ideas using variadic templates? I wasn't able to think of a way to use them to solve this problem.

Comment: @JasonMeziere, no not yet. I've been reading up on them trying to find a solution lol.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 This might be a question out of ignorance, but how does the initializer list allocate memory? More specifically, would it be possible to pass a vector the begin() and end() methods from the initializer list to the constructor of the vector?

Comment: @JasonMeziere, I'm not sure about the first question, but yes you can construct a vector using the `begin()` and `end()` methods from the initializer list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{1,2,3}` has no type, and cannot be deduced in `const std::vector<T> &`, they might be with `std::initializer_list<T>` though.

So, you might change call to:

```
std::vector<int> flat_array =
    flatten(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>{{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}},{{7,8,9},{10,11,12}}});
```

Comment: I did some digging and tried to look for a better solution than this, but as far as I can tell since the types of initializer lists cannot be deduced as template arguments this might be the best you can get. The second paragraph in the "Notes" section on this page sums it up pretty well: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Answer (score 1):

All I can do is save you from writing these nested `std::vector<std::vector<...` arguments:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>


template<typename Y, size_t N, typename T>
struct Flattener : public Flattener<Y, N-1, std::initializer_list<T>> {
    std::vector<Y> flatten(std::initializer_list<T> l) {
        std::vector<Y> vec;
        for (auto & e : l)
        {
            std::vector<Y> nvec = Flattener<Y, N, Y>{}.flatten(e); 
            vec.insert(end(vec), begin(nvec), end(nvec)); // Change this to a move, copies are no fun!
        }
        return vec;
    };
    using Flattener<Y, N-1, std::initializer_list<T>>::flatten;
};

template<typename Y, typename T>
struct Flattener<Y, 0, T> {
    std::vector<Y> flatten(Y y) { return {{y}}; };
};

int main()
{
    auto v = Flattener<int, 10, int>{}.flatten({{{1,2}, {3,4,5}}});
    for (auto e : v) std::cout << e << std::endl;
}
```

[(ideone link)](https://ideone.com/ipfG2R)

`Flattener<int, 10, int>` creates a class which has member functions `flatten` with overloads to unpack down to 10 levels deep nested `std::initializer_list` into a single `std::vector<int>`.

As you see you need to know the type at the lowest level (`int`) and a maximum depth (`10`) though.

---

`Flattener<int, 2, int>` has

- member function `flatten(std::initializer_list<int>)`
- base class `Flattener<int, 1, std::initializer_list<int>>` and *its* member functions. It has:

  - member function `flatten(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>>)`
  - base class `Flattener<int, 0, std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>>>` and *its* member functions. It has:

    - member function `flatten(int)`

Thus, the `Flattener<int, 2, int>` class has these member functions:

- `flatten(int)`
- `flatten(std::initializer_list<int>)`
- `flatten(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>>)`

Therefore it allows to create a vector from integers which are nested in 0 up to 2 initializer lists :)

This also shows why I use two separate template parameters: The first (`Y`) is the inner type and just threaded through, the second (`T`) helps to build up the nested initializer lists.  One could get rid of `Y` by extracting the inner type from `T`, but that's in the end just more complex than the current solution :)

Comment: This answer is pretty good, but that hardcoded maximum depth still doesn't feel quite right. There's got to be a way to do it entirely dynamically for any arbitrary depth without hardcoding it.

Comment: As you've found in your answer it seems that without hard coded depth it won't work...

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell you are right. Although C++ usually has some obscure way of making it do what you want lol. Either way I upvoted your answer because it's the best solution I've seen.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand how this works... How did you make the function accept a nested initializer list as the input!? Everything I've tried fails to compile haha and I just can't quite wrap my head around this example.

Comment: For example why do `T` and `Y` need to be two separate template parameters when they both are `int`? And that `using` statement has me really confused, but taking it out breaks the whole thing.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 Added an example / explanation :)

Comment: Thank you! That clarifies a lot of things haha

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it looks like the official answer to the question is no. :(

**From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization:**

> A braced-init-list is not an expression and therefore has no type, e.g. `decltype({1,2})` is ill-formed. Having no type implies that template type deduction cannot deduce a type that matches a braced-init-list, so given the declaration `template<class T> void f(T);` the expression `f({1,2,3})` is ill-formed.

The other answers provide some decent alternatives. None are quite as clean as I would like though.

---

## Edit:

This is the cleanest solution I've been able to come up with and it will work for vectors that hold types other than `int` as well. I had to wrap the functions in structs because you can't partially specialize function templates in C++.

This will automatically figure out the depth for you so you don't need to specify it as a template parameter, but it still doesn't accept an arbitrarily nested initializer list as input though so you need to explicitly state the type of the input...

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct dimensions : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

template <typename T>
struct dimensions<std::vector<T>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1 + dimensions<T>::value> {};

template <typename List, typename T, size_t N=dimensions<List>::value>
struct flatten
{
    std::vector<T> operator()(const List& l)
    {
        std::vector<T> v;

        for (const auto& e : l)
        {
            std::vector<T> tmp = flatten<decltype(e), T, N - 1>()(e);
            v.insert(v.end(), tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
        }

        return v;
    }
};

template <typename List, typename T>
struct flatten<List, T, 1>
{
    std::vector<T> operator()(const List& l)
    {
        return std::vector<T>(l.begin(), l.end());
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> l = {
        { { 0, 1}, { 2, 3 } },
        { { 4, 5}, { 6, 7 } },
    };

    std::vector<int> f = flatten<decltype(l), int>()(l);
}
```